# How to stop debian from mounting a partition at startup

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I installed Debian and set a data partition and now I want to stop it from mounting it everytime but deleting the line in `fstab` and updating initramfs won't stop it from mounting it. Is there a way to stop debian from mounting a partition at startup ?

Comment: neither of your solutions worked, it was like update initramfs hadn't any effect at all, so I just reinstalled debian without installing a default partition appart from root

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add to `/etc/fstab` the mounting point with the option `noauto`. For example:

```
/dev/sda    /media    ext4     defaults,noauto    0    0
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/165702/how-can-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-mounting-particular-partitions-deivices

Answer (score 0):

[This relevant documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-gpt-auto-generator.html)
suggests that there's systemd magic involved to mount other and more partitions than those mentioned in `/etc/fstab`.

A remedy against this magic would be the following command sequence:

```
# mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system-generators
# ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system-generators/systemd-gpt-auto-generator
```